# CSS - fixed position header & page border combination

Tags: html, css

My requirement is a page with a fixed position header and full border around the page.

Setting this up is simple, but I have a problem with the fixed position header overlapping the page border.

Visually, this shows the problem:

[image]

You can see the fixed position header overlaps the border on the right. My aim is to prevent this from happening.

This the relevant block of code I believe - testing this by setting position to relative, for example, will stop the header overlapping the right border, but I need the header to be fixed.

```
.site-header {
  min-height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Here is a pen to demonstrate the issue in full:

http://codepen.io/juxprose/pen/vERQQr

Any ideas? I've tried some z-index experiments as that appears to be the issue, but no luck. The 100% width also seems related to the issue. Any pointers much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `width: 100%` with `right: 10px` and `left: 10px`

```
.site-header {
  min-height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyKGyJ

---

Result

[image]

Comment: Hold on, did I downvote? I tried to accept the answer, then hit the upvote button

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your css to this:

```
.site-header {
  min-height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.site-main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px 25px;
  z-index:-2;
}
```

It's working on CodePen - hope it works for you too.

http://codepen.io/juxprose/pen/vERQQr

Comment: Yep that will solve the overlapping problem, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please add left and right 10px then it will solve